# Best practice to asynchronously delete a ListView/RecyclerView item

Tags: android, database, listview, asynchronous, android-recyclerview

I have a `ListView` with a `CursorLoader`. The user can open `ListView` items (open another `Fragment`) or delete items. All database actions occur asynchronously and usually it takes a fraction of a second. But technically the user could delete an item and then open the item before the deletion callback and cause and error. What's the best way to handle this? Here are the options I see.

1. Just assume that the `AsyncTask` will always happen quickly enough to avoid a problem
2. Do the database operation on the UI thread
3. Invalidate the `ListView` before the `AsyncTask` (but this would cause a flash in the UI)
4. Block user input somehow during the `AsyncTask`

**Edit:** I ended up using `RecyclerView` but I can't call `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(itemPos)` until after I have deleted the item from the database.

Answer (score 6):

Best option in your case will be using `RecyclerView`. Because when you clicked delete you can call `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(itemPos)`. So the list item will be removed with animation from your `RecyclerView` and you will not worry about the delete operation result.

See the Android Developer tutorial on [Creating Lists and Cards](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html):

> Use the [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) widget when you have data collections whose
>   elements change at runtime based on user action or network events.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
private static Context sContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    sContext = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    holder.mNameTextView.setOnClickListener(MyAdapter.this);

    holder.mNameTextView.setTag(holder);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mNameTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (view.getId() == holder.mNameTextView.getId()) {
        **//Important !!!**
        notifyItemRemoved(getPosition());
        // Make your database operation also here
    }
}



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mNumberRowTextView;
    public TextView mNameTextView;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mNameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to mDataset.remove(position) and notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size()). Without the latter you'll get crash when deleting first item till the list is empty.

Comment: What if I am using a Cursor? I can't remove the item from the data set until I get a new cursor.

Comment: You do not need to wait for your new cusosr. Just delete item from your recyclerView first. NotifyItemRemoved is accepting position as parameter. So just pass the position of where you clicked delete button. I mean you do not need to put your notifyItemRemoved after you get your new cursor. Change the priority and call notifyItemRemoved firstly when you clicked delete button. NotifyItemRemived doesn't look your data, it only removes your recycler view item from your list. Then you can also remove your data from your db @cambunctious

Comment: I tried and it does not work. The documentation is very clear that `notifyItemRemoved` is to notify the adapter that the item **has been removed** from the data set

Comment: Ok just another idea, I assume you can create POJO for your database dataSets, and you can create your adapter to show content from `List<YourPOJO>` , by this way, you can easily remove your data from your list and can update UI quickly. I mean your codes will be look like these ; `myList.remove(itemPos)` , `notifyItemRemoved(itemPos)` , `db.deleteRecord(itemPos)`

Comment: Did you check this method @cambunctious ?

Comment: recyclerview solution must be accepted answer. notifyDataSetChanged() and other notify method is so good when you working with list of items.

Answer (score 3):

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View itemView = convertView != null ? convertView : /* inflate view */;
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        itemView.setEnabled(false);
                        // OR view.setClickable(false);
                    }
                });
        return itemView;
    }
```

Or use RecyclerView with removal animation.

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)
                findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this)
                    .inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView valueTextView;
            private Button deleteButton;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                valueTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_text);
                deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
                deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int position = (int) v.getTag();
                        items.remove(position);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
                    }
                });
            }

            public void bind(int position) {
                valueTextView.setText(items.get(position));
                deleteButton.setTag(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disabling the view would be assuming that the item is not and will not be bound to another view, right? Could you point me to the key methods I should look at in RecyclerView? That looks like an interesting option if its not over-complicating.

Comment: That's actually super-easy:) Just added code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your **database query is not returning lot of data** then there is no issue to do database operations on UI thread.

Comment: this happens to be *most likely true* in my case but I'm hesitant to adopt this. The amount of data depends on the number of items that the user created. Also the amount of data can easily increase as the app evolves.